# Binding ng model by key of loop issue

Tags: javascript, angularjs, bind, angularjs-ng-model

I'm trying to bind value to `ng-model=""` directive because I'm displaying elements with it in loop.

I tried like this

```
<div class="form-group">
    <div data-ng-repeat="(key, n) in langInput.values">
        <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 u-no-padding">
            <label class="sell__label" for="auction_name_account_{{n.selected }}">Główna nazwa Twojej aukcji ({{n.selected }}):</label>
            <div class="pst-relative">
                <input type="text"
                       id="auction_name_account_{{n.selected }}"
                       class="form-control"
                       name="auction_name_account"
                       data-ng-model="inputs.auction_name_account[key]"
                       data-ng-minlength="10"
                       data-ng-maxlength="60"
                       required />
                <span class="sell__input-text sell__input-text--big-input" data-ng-show="sellItem.auction_name_account.$error.required">Wymagane!</span>
                <span class="sell__input-text sell__input-text--big-input" data-ng-show="sellItem.auction_name_account.$error.minlength">Za krótkie!</span>
                <span class="sell__input-text sell__input-text--big-input" data-ng-show="sellItem.auction_name_account.$error.maxlength">Za długie!</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I need to have unique models to firstly create working validation (spans below) and to gather and send data to rest api later on.

This `[key]` somehow doesn't print as key of object which is number but as normal string as I see in console.

Data of langInput is

```
$scope.langInput = {
    values: [
        {
            id: 1,
            selected: "pl"
        },
        {
            id: 2,
            selected: "eng"
        }
    ],
```

And I would like to have `ng-model="inputs.auction_name_account[1]"` where 1 is binded value or something similiar. Also above array of objects changes.

Comment: can you explain better in https://plnkr.co/edit/l740ia2y148zEPhoAdiK?p=preview

Comment: ng model of input is `inputs.auction_name_account[key]` in DOM what you can suspect in browser console
i want it to be `inputs.auction_name_account[1]` and `inputs.auction_name_account[2]`
https://plnkr.co/edit/c4tOS0KBzTtzVAKSyq2b?p=preview

Answer (score -1):

`auction_name_account` is going to be an Object when it's produced.

This means all property accessors must be a string and that properties which aren't a string, will be typecasted into one.  This is why, while `key` is an integer, it will be casted as a string upon usage.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors#Property_names

Comment: I edited object to contain only strings and ng model in browser console is still `inputs.auction_name_account[key] `look https://plnkr.co/edit/c4tOS0KBzTtzVAKSyq2b?p=preview

Comment: This is because you haven't declared `inputs`. AngularJS will try and declare variables as you use it, but it won't do it on just accessors. `inputs` needs to exist first. Define it using `$scope.input = {};`

Comment: It still doesn't work.. https://plnkr.co/edit/C9t2q8fNxYV56nnDtacM?p=preview Man take a look at plunker, try your idea and then write it if it help

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/zaHPNWHhDSLwYZIKvmXh?p=preview the only change I made was using `{{inputs}}` so you could see the contents of the object. After typing more than 10 characters in each input field, I could see the contents `inputs` changing.

Comment: Your plunker doesn't work at my machine. ng-model of inputs is still [tab]

Comment: I see that I'm able to print this object but I can't do angularjs validation basing on it `{{inputs.auction_name_account[0].$error.required }} <!-- its not boolean -->`  that's why I want to have my ng-models unique